# Call upon multiple animation events on player

Tags: c#, if-statement, animation, events, unity-game-engine

If I have a player and let's say a red ball hits my player and the player goes on fire... OK easy enough I did that. But now I want to add to the code below under the `if` statement that a blue ball hits my player and freezes or a black ball and causes death animation... But it's just not working out to add multiple animation events to 1 player.

```
Public GameObject GoneGo; 

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collisionObject)
{
    if (collisionObject.gameObject.tag == "Orb")
    {

        PlayGone();
    }
}

void PlayGone()
{
    GameObject gone = (GameObject)Instantiate(GoneGo);

    gone.transform.position = transform.position;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is perform a name check on the collider that impacts the player. You already have it checked the tag, have it check for redball,blueball, or blackball as the GameObject name afterwards.

You can handle multiple animations by looking into unitys mechanim system, which is the animator component (not animation component).
https://community.mixamo.com/hc/en-us/articles/203879268-Unity-Mecanim-Animation-Basics

What you would do after setting up the animator is have it SetTrigger for different trigger parameters. Or, you could use something like SetBool with a bool in the parameters like HitByBlueBall or HitByRedBall.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will def look into it now...i just wish Unity would make this easy haha...but i thank you for your time and i def will upvote